# More robust way of extracting date field from string in shell script

Tags: regex, bash, date, cut

I have a string which described the active directory expiration date of my account. I want to use/parse this string and do something when expiration date is coming soon. Now I have a problem extracting the date-part of the complete string. The string is:

```
Password expires             1-4-2015 15:41:05
```

I want to extract `1-4-2014` from it, but when the date is `20-12-2015`, the mechanism should also work. Unfortunately I'm unable to config the source system so that it outputs leading zero's. I have tried piping the string to `cut -c30-39`, but obviously this does not work with strings which are in total longer (like `20-12-2015`).

So I'm looking for a more robust solution, something like extracting extracting until the last 4 digits AFTER the 2nd `-`-character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use grep,

```
$ echo 'Password expires             1-4-2015 15:41:05' | grep -o '\b[0-9]\{1,2\}-[0-9]\{1,2\}-[0-9]\{4\}\b'
1-4-2015
$ echo 'Password expires             20-12-2015 15:41:05' | grep -o '\b[0-9]\{1,2\}-[0-9]\{1,2\}-[0-9]\{4\}\b'
20-12-2015
```

To grep only the year.

```
$ echo 'Password expires             20-12-2015 15:41:05' | grep -oP '^(?:[^-]*-){2}\K\d{4}\b'
2015
```

To get only the day

```
$ echo 'Password expires             1-4-2015 15:41:05' | grep -oP '\b[0-9]{1,2}(?=-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{4}\b)'
1
```

To get only the month

```
$ echo 'Password expires             1-4-2015 15:41:05' | grep -oP '\b[0-9]{1,2}-\K[0-9]{1,2}(?=-[0-9]{4}\b)'
4
```

Comment: Working great, thanks! I tried to also grep only month and day, but could not fix this. Can you help with that? In this case `1` is the day and `4` is the month.

Answer (score 1):

Either:

```
awk "{print $3}"
```

Or

```
tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 3
```

That's assuming you are after "third thing" on the line. Then use `date` to parse, and verify. Unfortunately, because it's ambiguous, your date string won't parse.

You'd need to reverse it - some versions of `date` have `-f` input format specifier, but not all. (I'm fairly sure if you used Perl, Time::Piece and strptime, you'd be able to do this too, but suspect that's out of scope)

```
date -d "2015-1-4 15:41:05" +"%s"
#1420386065
```

Which you can then numerically compare against `date +"%s"` to check how soon it's coming. You can use `cut` or `awk` to extract your date fields.

```
NEWDATE=`echo $MYDATE | awk -F- '{print $3"-"$2"-"$1}'`
date -d "$NEWDATE $TIME" +"%s"
```

Stringing together might end up something like this:

```
STRING="Password expires             1-4-2015 15:41:05"

DATE=`echo $STRING | awk '{print $3}'`
TIME=`echo $STRING | awk '{print $4}'`

NEWDATE=`echo $DATE | awk -F- '{print $3"-"$2"-"$1}'`

EPOCH_EXP=`date -d "$NEWDATE $TIME" +"%s"`
EPOCH_TIME=`date +"%s"`

EXPIRES_S=$(($EPOCH_TIME - $EPOCH_EXP))
echo "Password expires in $EXPIRES_S seconds"
```

(I'm sure this could be done better, but this is mostly aimed as an illustration)

Answer (score 0):

Without regex for the two samples:

```
$ echo "Password expires             1-4-2015 15:41:05"  | tr -s " " | cut -d' ' -f3
1-4-2015

$ echo "Password expires             20-4-2015 15:41:05"  | tr -s " " | cut -d' ' -f3
20-4-2015
```